# Node's childProcess.spawn - piping doesn't work

Tags: node.js, shell, nginx, pipe, child-process

I want to read and parse (with `awk`) my nginx logs in realtime. So I wrote this shell command to do this, it works if I run it in shell:

```
tail -f -n +1 /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1, $7, $9}'
```

But I can't run it in node. I wrote this code to run my command (this is taken from the example in node.js docs), but it displays nothing:

```
const tail = childProcess.spawn('tail',['-f', '-n', '+1', nginxAccessLog]);
const awk = childProcess.spawn('awk', ['{print $1, $7, $9}'],  { stdio: [tail.stdout, 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
tail.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('tail output', data.toString());
})
awk.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('awk output', data.toString());
})
tail.on('error', () => 'tail error')
awk.on('error', () => 'awk error')
tail.on('close', () => console.log('tail end', result));
awk.on('close', () => console.log('awk end', result));
```

I can see that my process are spawned (they are in the `htop` output), but I have no output.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why passing `tail.stdout` to the Awk process doesn't work (I'm guessing that at the time the Awk process is created, `tail.stdout` might not yet have a valid file descriptor attached to it), but this does:

```
const tail = childProcess.spawn('tail',['-f', '-n', '+1', nginxAccessLog]);
const awk  = childProcess.spawn('awk', ['{print $1, $7, $9}'],  { stdio: [ 'pipe', process.stdout ] });

tail.stdout.pipe(awk.stdin);
```

Note that because you're using `tail -f`, the pipeline will keep running.

**EDIT**: if it's not your intention to *just* log the output, but also process it, the situation becomes a bit more involved because Awk buffers its output (up to 4K, I believe).

You need to force a flush in Awk, which [I found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83853) can be triggered using `fflush("")` or `system("")`. So the code becomes:

```
const tail = childProcess.spawn('tail',['-f', '-n', '+1', nginxAccessLog]);
const awk  = childProcess.spawn('awk', [ '{print $1, $7, $9; fflush(""); }']);

tail.stdout.pipe(awk.stdin);

awk.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('awk output:', data.toString());
});
```

This does seem to add empty lines to the output, but those can be filtered out I guess.

Comment: For me it crashes with `awk.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null`. If I'll comment out `awk.stdout.on('data', ...)` callback, it will display the output on terminal. But how I can get the `awk` output in callback, like in my question?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, I assumed that all you wanted to do is console.log the output. I'll edit my answer.